# Bootstrap 4 nav is not displayed in Angular 2+ & PrimeNG

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, primeng

I am trying with both PrimeNG & Bootstrap libraies in Angular 2+ project,
The Prime NG effect is showing but the Bootstarp Nav Bar is not getting displayed with its effects.

What I am missing?

The style angular-cli.json:

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/cupertino/theme.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",        
        "styles.css"
      ],
```

Here is the HTML section:

```
<div class="content-section implementation">
    <div class="row">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                            <i class="navbar-brand fa fa-bars"></i>
                            <span>BrandName</span>
                        </a>

                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <p-toolbar>
            <div class="ui-toolbar-group-right">             
                <p-contextMenu [target]="cToolbar" [model]="items"></p-contextMenu>
                <i #cToolbar class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </div>
        </p-toolbar>       
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: reverse the order of style sheets. It will work

Comment: @Aravind Thanks for replying. I have changed the order of the style sheets as you told. Still no effect in the nav bar.

Comment: It should work. you are having `p-toolbar` outside the `nav` is that right?

Comment: @Aravind, Yes I have kept it outside of <nav>. The <p-toolbar> is finely displayed with all its effects, but the nav is just displaying the items in <ul> <li> format .. no effects.. even no bar is displayed on top

Comment: It will be helpful is anyone help me.